# Python Script to enter data into javascript frame

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to write a python script using selenium to enter data into a javascript form.

I continue to get an error that the element can not be found.
This is what I tried so far:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime

eGBS = "xxxxx" #removed web address b/c of company info
rpt = '' #removed web address b/c of company info
wb = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\TEMP\chromedriver.exe')
wb.maximize_window()
wb.get(eGBS)
sleep(2)
loginClick = wb.find_element_by_link_text("Click here to login")
loginClick.click()
sleep(2)
ele1 = wb.find_element_by_id("desktop_dropdown")
ele1.click()
sleep(2)
ele2 = wb.find_element_by_id("WindowsAccountSelectId")
ele2.click()
glosub = wb.find_element_by_id("windowsSubmit")
glosub.click()
glosuccess = wb.find_element_by_id("successButtonId")
glosuccess.click()
sleep(2)
wb.get(rpt)
sleep(5) #code works to this point

# These next lines are what I have tried
#cf = wb.find_element_by_name('ff5')
#cf.click
#t = wb.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='ff5']")
#t.click
#ss = wb.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='40']") 
#ss.select
rr = wb.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Run Report']")
rr.click
```

This is the last error I received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\temp\GitHub\etl\NI\eGBS_DownloadRpt.py", line 33, in <module>
    cf = wb.find_element_by_name('ff5')
  File "C:\Users\cg1262\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 496, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\cg1262\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\cg1262\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\cg1262\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="ff5"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.85)
```

This is the element I'm trying to access:
[image]

Comment: I found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340361/find-a-td-element-using-selenium-python) which suggest that some elements (such as iFrames, Cells, or Tables <td> like the element you are trying to find) may not load by the time the script runs. But either way, my assumption is that because the element is a table element, find_element_by_name() might be the wrong function

Comment: Check if the element present inside an iframe?

Comment: it is inside an iframe. and it is inside of a table.  I tried by name and by xpath to no success... do I need to add another step here... I am also sleeping for 5 seconds to provide time for the frame to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `xpath` locator is wrong in `wb.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Run Report']")` line. We are not able to see the correct locator since you did not provide the link to the page
In case that element is inside `iframe` you need to switch to that `iframe` first.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python) post for example

Comment: Sorry it is an internal site.  However I sent the snipit of the html where I'm trying to find ff5... Run Report is one I was looking for too and it was not working but ff5 is the example I provided.

Comment: perfect.  Thank you... I needed to switch_to.frame(frameName)